# BeautifulSoup4 does not recognize css-selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using `Python 3.6.9` and I have installed on my venv the following packages:

```
beautifulsoup4 (4.10.0)
certifi (2021.10.8)
charset-normalizer (2.0.9)
idna (3.3)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
requests (2.26.0)
setuptools (39.0.1)
soupsieve (2.3.1)
urllib3 (1.26.7)
```

I am trying to write a simple web app that gets data from a website:

```
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getData():

    global link
    try:
        html_doc = """
        <div class="schedule nine columns" id="schedule">
         <p class="schedule-desc">
          Dates subject to change at any time by the manufacturer. If you have any questions regarding the release of any products or you see a conflicting release date, please contact us.
         </p>
         <div class="schedule-month">
          <h3>
           January, 2022
          </h3>
         </div>
         <div class="schedule-date">
          01/04/22
         </div>
         <div class="schedule-list clear">
          <div class="eight columns">
           <a class="schedule-product-title" href="/i/2020-21-leaf-superlative-collection-hobby-hockey-10-box-case">
            2020-21 Leaf Superlative Collection Hobby Hockey 10-Box Case
           </a>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="schedule-list clear">
          <div class="eight columns">
           <a class="schedule-product-title" href="/i/2020-21-leaf-superlative-collection-hockey-hobby-box">
            2020-21 Leaf Superlative Collection Hockey Hobby Box
           </a>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="schedule-list clear">
          <div class="eight columns">
           <a class="schedule-product-title" href="/i/2021-leaf-metal-draft-baseball-jumbo-box">
            2021 Leaf Metal Draft Baseball Jumbo Box
           </a>
          </div>
         </div>
                """

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

        results = soup.find(id="schedule")

        elem = results.find_all("div")

        resArr = []

        # use current date if no date exists
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        for ele in elem:

            scheduleDate = ele.select(".schedule-date")
            if len(scheduleDate) > 0:
                date = ele.select(".schedule-date").get_text()

            releaseStr = ele.select("div > div.eight.columns > a")
            if len(releaseStr) > 0:
                txt = releaseStr[0].get_text().strip()
                link = releaseStr[0].get("href").strip()

                dict = {"date": date, "releaseName": txt, "link": link}
                resArr.append(dict)

        return resArr
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


releaseCal = getData()
print(releaseCal)
```

However, the `css-selector` is not recognized by beautifulSoup. Even though the element has the selector:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

PS.: Any other code improvements are also highly welcome as I am always trying to get better with python!

Comment: If `ele` is already your `div` with `class="schedule-date"`, then why are you using the `select()` method on that `div`? I would discourage using a for loop here, and instead be explicit about the specific elements you are targeting to extract the relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `css-selector` is returning an empty list because the current iteration of `ele` already represents the element with `class="schedule-date"`. In your case, I would recommend removing the date component from the for loop and instead passing a list comprehension of your extracted elements to a `pd.DataFrame()` constructor. You can also leverage a `lambda` function to better handle the logic of defaulting your date to the current date if it does not exist. See below:

```
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)

def getData():

    html_doc = """
        your html here
    """

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

    df = pd.DataFrame([{'releaseName': i.text.strip(), 'link': i.get('href')} for i in soup.select('div.eight.columns > a')])

    default_date = lambda d: d[0].text.strip() if d else datetime.datetime.now()
    df['date'] = default_date(soup.select('.schedule-date'))

    return df

releaseCal = getData()
```

This yields the following:

```
                                         releaseName  \
0  2020-21 Leaf Superlative Collection Hobby Hock...   
1  2020-21 Leaf Superlative Collection Hockey Hob...   
2           2021 Leaf Metal Draft Baseball Jumbo Box   

                                                link      date  
0  /i/2020-21-leaf-superlative-collection-hobby-h...  01/04/22  
1  /i/2020-21-leaf-superlative-collection-hockey-...  01/04/22  
2        /i/2021-leaf-metal-draft-baseball-jumbo-box  01/04/22
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! However the date is still the current date. I would like to get this element `<div class="schedule-date">01/04/22</div>` and the date `01/04/22` as datetime object.

Comment: The date is correct....today is 1/02/22. You can use `pandas` to convert columns using `pd.to_datetime()`